# Validating User Input

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to deal with this on the back end.  When I submit my form I want to verify that there were selections made to both questions and the answers but still be able to tie in the right answers to the right questions.

```
<?php
<fieldset>

        <legend>Secret Questions</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="question1">Question #1:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="questions[]" id="question1">
                <option value="">- Select -</option>
                <?php
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
                    print "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['question']."</option>\r";
                }
                ?>
             </select>
        </dd>

    </dl>

    <dl>

        <dt><label for="answer">Answer:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="answers[]" id="answer" size="54" /></dd>

    </dl>

    <dl>

        <dt><label for="question2">Question #2:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="questions[]" id="question2">
                <option value="">- Select -</option>
                <?php
                mysqli_data_seek( $result, 0 );
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
                    print "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['question']."</option>\r";
                }
                ?>
             </select>
        </dd>

    </dl>

    <dl>

        <dt><label for="answer">Answer:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="answers[]" id="answer" size="54" /></dd>

    </dl>

    <dl class="submit">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />

    </dl>

</fieldset>
?>
```

Comment: You're asking about "best way", but have you implemented "*any* way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, you're looping wrong. You're iterating through the result twice when you could only do it once.

Place this at the beginning of the file:

```
$options = "";
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) { 
   $options .= "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".
                   $row['question']."</option>\r";
}
```

Then, place this where you are currently looping:

```
<?php echo $options; ?>
```

Now, to get to your question.

You're currently storing the question and answer as arrays (`<name>[]` translates to an array when received by PHP). Personally, I would probably store them as separate labels -- there really isn't much gained by placing them in an array unless you really need to iterate over several records (and that does not look like your current situation).

If you really need to use arrays, then be sure to assign indexes. You do this the same way you assign index in PHP (only no quotes -- see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) for more). This way you can have your first select have `<select name="question[q1]">`, the first answer as `<input type="text" name="answers[q1]" id="answer" size="54" />`, and the resulting $_REQUEST would have this:

```
$_REQUEST['question'] = array(
                              'q1' => /*first question value*/,
                               ... );

$_REQUEST['answer']   = array(
                              'q1' => /*first answer value*/,
                               ... );
```

As to what's best as far as data storage is concerned, that is really more of a use-case question. I'd imagine that it might be more beneficial to have the answers all in one array already, but I've no idea what your particular case is.

To validation, that depends on how you decide to proceed, but there are plenty of examples of PHP form validation. I suppose I will use the old quote, "The general result is left as an exercise to the reader".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `frontend` to check that the user has actually submitted anything for both questions, if so use `AJAX` wrapped in `jQuery` to send this data to your backend, do whatever checks you need, and then report back to the user.